# Sails.js : How i set a controller to not be accessible by http?

Tags: sails.js

I have written a controller in Sails that is only **used intern by other controllers**.

Something like:

```
module.exports = {
   get_active_ids: function(user) {
       ....
       return foo;
   }
}
```

Action blueprints is on (i need that for other controllers).

Now if i type domain.com/mycontroller i get a 404 or 504 (if i use a methodname form my controller).

I thought about 2 solution:

1. Move it to a service. But logical is a controller.
2. Write a manual redirect route for /controllername

Both dont seem good to me - anyone have another option?

Comment: This is exactly what services are for--code that is shared between controllers.  What makes you think that a controller is more logical for this use case?

Comment: Oh your right - sorry i get it wrong ;-)